# Why JS opens a txt file instead of downloading it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here is my code:

**Server Side:**

```
public function export(){
    $arr = array();
    if($_POST["type"] == "save"){
        $name = "export.txt";
        file_put_contents("$name",$_POST["text"]);
        $arr["type"] = "link";
        $arr["url"] = "http://localhost:8000/{$name}";
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

**Client Side:**

```
$(document).on('click', '#export', function () {
    var names = ["سعید خرمی", "فرید هادوی"];
    var namess = names.join('\n');
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/export",
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        data: {
            type: "save",
            text: namess
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            var href = data.url;
            window.location = href;
        }
    });
})
```

When I click on `#export` *(button)*, it opens that `.txt` file *(instead of downloading it)*. Something like this:

[image]

Noted that I use chrome .. Also it doesn't work in other browsers.

How can I force it to download that `.txt` file?

Comment: You should use PHP and send force download headers. If you directly redirect to the file URL and if the browser supports the file type to display, it will display the output instead of downloading.

Comment: Everything the browser displays has been downloaded.

Comment: @nnnnnn But I need to get a `.txt` file ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your success part like this,

```
success: function(data){
var href = download.php?filename=export.txt;
window.location = href;
}
```

And in your download.php:

Get the file name from the GET variable `filename` (say as `$file`).

Send the headers:

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['filename']; // get the filename
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: text/plain'); // the appropriate header type for txt file
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Source: [PHP Readfile Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: Also `$file` contains what? May you please write full code?

Comment: In $file you will get the filename which you send via Ajax. Updated in the answer.